# Loop through dictionary and get the 7 most common words. BUT only if the words aren't found in another list

Tags: python

I am learning some basic python 3 and have been stuck at this problem for 2 days now and i can't seem to get anywhere...
Been reading the "think python" book and I'm working on chapter 13 and the case study it contains. The chapter is all about reading a file and doing some magic with it like counting total number of words and the most used words.
One part of the program is about "Dictionary subtraction" where the program fetches all the word from one textfile *that are not found in another textfile*.

What I also need the program to do is count the most common word from the first file, excluding the  words found in the "dictionary" text file. This functionality has had me stuck for two days and i don't really know how to solve this...

The Code to my program is as follow:

```
import string

def process_file(filename):
  hist = {}
  fp = open(filename)


for line in fp:
    process_line(line, hist)
return hist


def process_line(line, hist):
    line = line.replace('-', ' ')

    for word in line.split():
        word = word.strip(string.punctuation + string.whitespace)
        word = word.lower()

        hist[word] = hist.get(word, 0) + 1


def most_common(hist):
    t = []
    for key, value in hist.items():
        t.append((value, key))

    t.sort()
    t.reverse()
    return t


def subtract(d1, d2):
    res = {}
    for key in d1:
        if key not in d2:
            res[key] = None
    return res


hist = process_file('alice-ch1.txt')
words = process_file('common-words.txt')
diff = subtract(hist, words)


def total_words(hist):
    return sum(hist.values())


def different_words(hist):
    return len(hist)


if __name__ == '__main__':

print ('Total number of words:', total_words(hist))
print ('Number of different words:', different_words(hist))

t = most_common(hist)
print ('The most common words are:')
for freq, word in t[0:7]:
    print (word, '\t', freq)
print("The words in the book that aren't in the word list are:")
for word in diff.keys():
    print(word)
```

I then created a test dict containing a few words and imaginary times they occur and a test list to try and solve my problem and the code for that is:

```
histfake = {'hello': 12, 'removeme': 2, 'hi': 3, 'fish':250, 'chicken':55, 'cow':10, 'bye':20, 'the':93, 'she':79, 'to':75}
listfake =['removeme', 'fish']

newdict = {}
for key, val in histfake.items():
    for commonword in listfake:
        if key != commonword:
            newdict[key] = val
        else:
            newdict[key] = 0

sortcommongone = []
for key, value in newdict.items():
    sortcommongone.append((value, key))
sortcommongone.sort()
sortcommongone.reverse()

for freq, word in sortcommongone:
    print(word, '\t', freq)
```

The problem is that that code only works for one word. Only one matched word between the dict and the list gets the value of 0 (thought that I could give the duplicate words the vale 0 since I only need the 7 most common words that are not found in the common-word text file.
How can I solve this? Created a account here just to try and get some help with this since Stackowerflow has helped me before with other problems. But this time I needed to ask the question myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out the items using a `dict` comprehension

```
>>> {key: value for key, value in histfake.items() if key not in listfake}
{'hi': 3, 'she': 79, 'to': 75, 'cow': 10, 'bye': 20, 'chicken': 55, 'the': 93, 'hello': 12}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If i follow your code it works on my example with histfake and listfake. Although if I try to apply this solution to the actual problem with the 2 textfiles it doesn't work. It still prints out that the most occurring words are 'the' and 'she' which both are words in the textfile the program should exclude in the counting

Answer (score 0):

Unless *listfake* is larger than *histfake* ,the most efficient way will be to delete keys in it *listfake*

```
for key in listfake:
    del histfake[key]
```

Complexity of list comprehension and this solution is O(n)- but the list is supposedly much shorter than the dictionary.

**EDIT:**
Or it may be done - if you have more keys than actual words - 
for key in histfake:
    if key in listfake:
        del histfake[key]
 You may want to [test run time](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/timeit.html)

Then, of course, you'll have to sort dictionary into list - and recreate it

```
from operator import itemgetter    
most_common_7 = dict(sorted(histfake.items(), key=itemgetter(1))[:7])
```

BTW, you may use [*Counter* from *Collections*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count words. And maybe part of your problem is that you don't remove all non-letter characters from your text

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Well, the real list in trying to check agains is a text-file with 1000 lines with one word on each line. The other file is only 200 lines long containing a chapter from a Alice in Wonderland. So in my real problem with the files i guess the list is longer than the real dictionary.
I get an error when i try your code, itemgetter is not defined. Is it something that needs an import or should I predefine it as something?

Comment: Although when I sort it by using the same technique by using sortcommongone as I do in my original answer-post I get it to work. Although when i try your solution with the "real" dictionary created from the text file and the "real" list created from the common-words file it doesn't work anymore. I get error: TypeError uneatable type: 'list'. I get this error even when I try and shorten the common-words file to just 3 words. Guessing the problem is that the file isn't writeable?

Comment: @Dan, I did not test my solution initially. But it does work. I have a nagging suspicion that your problem is somehow related to the way you process data from files.

Comment: I got it to work by scrapping the entire code and presented the problem to my class forum from university. Thanks for helping though! :)